# How to suppress "Member has protected access" in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I want to suppress (disable) a waring in PhpStorm a message "Member has protected access" for a certain places (not in all code).

Example:

[image]

### What I have tried

[Link 1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/suppressing-inspections.html): on `Alt + Enter` I do not have anything connected to the message so that I could disable it. As well as I do not have this message in inspection results when *Running Inspections*.

[Link 2](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html) I do not have the message in *Inspection Settings* so I can not disable it.

Another try: using `@noinspection`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/discordier/ed4b9cba14652e7212f5) and [here](https://www.evoweb.de/allgemeine-entwicklung/tools/phpstorm-noinspection.html) I did not find needed message.

There were suggestion to disable suppress all errors with `Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> Erros and Warnings -> Errors`. But it is not what I need.

Is there no way to do it?

Comment: AFAIK -- you cannot. Accessing protected members from outside is considered an serious error (lexer/parser level I think) and not just some warning that can be supressed. You have to specify right typehint where `connection` will not be protected property or use some plugin that does it in background somehow (that targets mocks in particular). No better ideas.

Comment: @LazyOne `$mock` is mock object of a class. For the test I make all properties of `$mock` public. There is no other way to test it.

Comment: I know what Mock is. But IDE does not: it does not know that in your code `connection` is a public property from `$mock` and not from `FTP` (as per your PHPDoc). There is a workaround via PHPDoc ... but that means creating custom class (where such properties will be declared public) -- too much hassle just to satisfy an IDE/not practical at all. So if anything .. it better be done via some plugin that can typehint `$mock` dynamically without you providing such PHPDoc

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is implement the `__set` magic method into your class, which will transform these warnings into "notices".

```
/**
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function __set($name, $value) {
  throw new \Exception(sprintf('Property "%s" does not exist in %s.', $name, __CLASS__));
}
```

Since PHPStorm can't analyse your code to make sure this property is settable through the magic method, it can't know whether it's an error or not.

Of course, it's kind of an ugly workaround, and means that runtime "Cannot access protected property" fatal errors will now be exceptions, which may or may not be fine in your case.

Comment: I found this page, but I do not want to write a __set method but suppress the error inspection